# Java - Program outputs and else statement for no reason?

Tags: if-statement

I have a really simple quadratic formula code I wrote a while ago and got back to. It runs fine, but it outputs my final else statement even though it shouldn't!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class quadFormGUI {
public void quadForm(){

    String aNumI = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your 'A' variable?");
    String bNumI = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your 'B' variable?");
    String cNumI = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your 'C' variable?");

    double aNum = Double.parseDouble(aNumI);
    double bNum = Double.parseDouble(bNumI);
    double cNum = Double.parseDouble(cNumI);

    double oneAns = (bNum * bNum) + (-aNum * cNum * 4);
    if (oneAns < 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The equation does not have a solution", "Quadratic Formula" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }else{
        double twoAns = (double) Math.sqrt(oneAns);
        double threeAns = -bNum + twoAns;
        double xOne = threeAns/(2*aNum);

        double fourAns = (bNum * bNum) + (-aNum * cNum * 4);
        double fiveAns = (double) Math.sqrt(fourAns);
        double sixAns = -bNum - fiveAns;
        double xTwo = sixAns/(2*aNum);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"X1 is " + xOne + " & X2 is " +xTwo, "Quadratic Formula" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        xOne = xOne * -1;
        xTwo = xTwo * -1;
        if (xOne < 0 && xTwo < 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,aNum +"(X " + xOne + ") (X " + xTwo + ")", "Quadratic Formula" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }else if (xOne < 0 && xTwo > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,aNum +"(X " + xOne + ") (X + " + xTwo + ")", "Quadratic Formula" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }else if (xOne > 0 && xTwo < 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,aNum +"(X + " + xOne + ") (X " + xTwo + ")", "Quadratic Formula" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }else if (xOne > 0 && xTwo > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,aNum +"(X + " + xOne + ") (X + " + xTwo + ")", "Quadratic Formula" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }
}
}
```

It always outputs "Wrong" no matter what!

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Nothing, my code runs, everything works just as I wanted, except it does the last else statement no matter what too.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Everything clearly *does not work just as you want*, or you wouldn't have any reason to post here. Set a breakpoint at `if (oneAns < 0)` and try again. Step through the code line by line and look at the values of your variables. It shows you **exactly** what the values are that lead you into the *wrong* statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes yes, sorry, I was incorrect. Now thinking back on it, why was I checking for X to be 0? Anyway, the program works fine, I was just always inputting A = 0, B = -3, C = 0. I fixed it, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing "Wrong" on the console, your program flow is going to the last "else" part. This means that **either xOne or xTwo or both are 0**. The only way xOne or xTwo can  be zero is if you enter 0s for a and c. There is also another possibility that in your JOptionPane showInputBox, you are not pressing Ok button after entering a value; you might be pressing the cancel button in which case a null value will be returned and stored in your String variables aNumI, bNumI and cNumI. Except for these 2 cases, your program cannot go to the else part. I executed your very program in an online IDE and it is not going to the else part. The only difference is that I am not using JOptionPane.

Try to print or debug the values of aNumI, bNumI and cNumI right after the input boxes are closed. I am sure they will be either null or have '0'. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: Wouldn't `Double.parseDouble(String)` throw an exception if string is NULL? It must be zero don't you think?

Comment: That's right.  I didn't know that parseDouble throws an NPE if the given string is null.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As I said before, the program WORKS. It calculates everything, and goes into one of those correct if statements. The problem is it doesn't just stop, it keeps checking the statements (which obviously none of the others are true) but lands on `else`

Comment: @StealthVice7, as per your self-answer, you are admitting that you were indeed entering a 0 for both a and c which resulted in your program flow going to the else block. Are you still looking to get help on something else?

Comment: @StealthVice7. Cool then. Don't forget the mark the response that answered your question. The responders deserve reputation. :)